# How to configure Azure AD in SQL Server for authentication?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

We need to configure `Azure SQL server` with `Azure AD` such that while connecting to `Azure SQL server` through `JDBC` our users should be able to use their `AD username` and `password`.

We are unable to find documentations on how to setup `Azure AD` with `Azure SQL server`.

We are looking for some documentation or some steps to configure `Azure AD` with `Azure SQL server`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, while creating the Azure SQL Server, you need to make sure to choose Use only **Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) Authentication** in **Authentication method** option.

[image]

> The JDBC driver allows you to specify your Azure Active Directory
> credentials in the JDBC connection string to connect to Azure SQL
> Database.

To know how to configure Azure Active Directory authentication visit Microsoft official document [Connecting to SQL Database By Using Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-overview).

To connect the Azure SQL Database with Azure AD through JDBC, there is a proper setup required in which you need to install and configure some prerequisites. This [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver15) from Microsoft will guide you to do same.

Comment: Thanks @UtkarshPal-MT! Is it possible to configure Azure AD in SQL server installed on Azure VM?

Comment: Connecting to a SQL Server instance that's running on an Azure virtual machine (VM) is not supported using Azure Active Directory or Azure Active Directory Domain Services. Use an Active Directory domain account instead.